# Loading scraped data into Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I have combined some tutorials on web scraping and made a simple web crawler that is scraping new posted question here on SO. I want to load them into mine postgresql data base, but I am having trouble with a decoding error that my crawler is showing me.

Error:

```
2015-06-09 06:07:10+0200 [stack] ERROR: Error processing {'title': u'Laravel 5 Confused when implements ShoudlQueue',
     'url': u'/questions/30722718/laravel-5-confused-when-implements-shoudlqueue'}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 62, in _process_chain
        return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 65, in process_chain
        d.callback(input)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 393, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 501, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/home/petarp/Documents/PyScraping/RealPython/WebScraping/stack/stack/pipelines.py", line 27, in process_item
        session.commit()
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 790, in commit
        self.transaction.commit()
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 392, in commit
        self._prepare_impl()
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 372, in _prepare_impl
        self.session.flush()
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2004, in flush
        self._flush(objects)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2122, in _flush
        transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
        compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2086, in _flush
        flush_context.execute()
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 373, in execute
        rec.execute(self)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 532, in execute
        uow
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 174, in save_obj
        mapper, table, insert)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 761, in _emit_insert_statements
        execute(statement, params)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
        return meth(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
        return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
        compiled_sql, distilled_params
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
        context)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1341, in _handle_dbapi_exception
        exc_info
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
        reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
        context)
      File "/home/petarp/.virtualenvs/webscraping/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
        cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "url" of relation "reals" does not exist
    LINE 1: INSERT INTO reals (title, url) VALUES ('Laravel 5 Confused w...
                                      ^
     [SQL: 'INSERT INTO reals (title, url) VALUES (%(title)s, %(url)s) RETURNING reals.id'] [parameters: {'url': u'/questions/30722718/laravel-5-confused-when-implements-shoudlqueue', 'title': u'Laravel 5 Confused when implements ShoudlQueue'}]
```

I have used sqlalchemy to define connection between crawler and postgresql. Here are settings.py, models.py and pipelines.py.

Settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'stack'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['stack.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'stack.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['stack.pipelines.StackPipeline']
# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
# USER_AGENT = 'stack (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'
DATABASE = {
    'drivername': 'postgres',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
    'username': '********',
    'password': '********',
    'database': '********'
}
```

Models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

import settings


DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()


def db_connect():
    """ Performs database connections using database settings from settings.py
        Returns sqlalchemy engine instance
    """
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))


def create_reals_table(engine):
    """"""
    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)


class Reals(DeclarativeBase):
    """SQLAlchemy Reals Model"""
    __tablename__ = 'reals'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String)
    url = Column('url', String, nullable=True)
```

Pipeline.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Reals, db_connect, create_reals_table


class StackPipeline(object):
    """ Stack Exchange pipeline for storing scraped items in the database """
    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize database connection and sessionmaker """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_reals_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """Save reals in database.
        This method is called for every item pipeline componenet."""
        session = self.Session()
        real = Reals(**item)

        try:
            session.add(real)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
        return item
```

Shema for real table:

```
realpython=# select * from reals limit 5;
 id | title | link 
----+-------+------
(0 rows)
```

Can someone help me understand what is going one in here, and decode this?

Comment: Could you check that your `reals` table actually contains all the required columns?

Comment: provide the schema of `reals` it looks like there is no column url in it

Comment: Yes you are right, there is no column url in it.

Comment: edited mine question, should I drop and recreate the table?

Comment: No just give the url input to the link column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is actually self-explanatory — you just have to look at the last few lines:

> `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "url" of relation "reals" does not exist`

So, you either need to change your SQL to insert into a column named `link`, or you need to rename the column in the table with [`ALTER TABLE reals RENAME COLUMN link TO url;`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

The problem was in the `url`, `link` definition in my `Items.py`, I have defined it like this, and in mine models I'm creating a schema table whit `link`, so I just replace `url` whit `link` and the data is loaded successful into the postgresql.

```
from scrapy import Item, Field


    class StackItem(Item):
        # define the fields for your item here like:
        # name = scrapy.Field()
        title = Field()
        url = Field()
```

New Items.py:

```
from scrapy import Item, Field


class StackItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
```

The desired result:

```
 id |                                 title                                  |                                          link                                          
----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | pointcut execution for specific class constructor                      | /questions/30723494/pointcut-execution-for-specific-class-constructor
  2 | PWX-00001 Error opening repository “dtlmsg.txt”. RCs = 268/150/2       | /questions/30723493/pwx-00001-error-opening-repository-dtlmsg-txt-rcs-268-150-2
  3 | Can anyone share a sample c++ program, that reads ASCII stl type file? | /questions/30723491/can-anyone-share-a-sample-c-program-that-reads-ascii-stl-type-file
  4 | Where should I do the core logic code in express js?                   | /questions/30723487/where-should-i-do-the-core-logic-code-in-express-js
  5 | configuring rails application to make ui router work                   | /questions/30723485/configuring-rails-application-to-make-ui-router-work
(5 rows)
```

Comment: And yes I have needed to alter the schema url column to be link.